# building android error java version

Tags: android, building

I'm newbie in building android OS.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  and the JDK 8.

The envsetup.sh gives :

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-85-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
```

And I try to compile with ***make -J4***

I get the foolowing error :

```
============================================
You asked for an OpenJDK 7 build but your version is
java version "1.8.0_92" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode).
************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:220: *** stop.
make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Erreur 1
============================================
```

So I change the JDK to version 7 but I get the same error but inverted :

```
============================================
You asked for an OpenJDK 8 build but your version is
java version "1.7.x" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.x) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode).
************************************************************
```

So what is the pb ?

How can I solve it ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but I'm working with Android 6 today, so I went through the same issue... For me, this helped:

If you want to force using Java 8, you can use this:

```
export EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA8=1
```

Then make again:

```
m
```

But, as the name says, it is experimental, thus not recommended.

For me (Ubuntu 18.04.1), I had to download Java 7 (https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/7) and:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo tar zxf /tmp/openjdk-7u75-b13-linux-x64-18_dec_2014.tar.gz
sudo chown root:root java-se-7u75-ri -R
```

The above will create `/usr/lib/jvm/java-se-7u75-ri` and set it as owned by user and group `root`.

Now add it to `PATH`, as stated in https://source.android.com/setup/build/building#wrong-java-version:

> [...] Prepend the correct JDK to the beginning of your path or remove the problematic JDK.

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-se-7u75-ri/bin:$PATH"
```

I also had to patch `build/core/main.mk`:

```
diff --git a/core/main.mk b/core/main.mk
index a6f829ab6..97690add0 100644
--- a/core/main.mk
+++ b/core/main.mk
@@ -153,7 +153,7 @@ javac_version := $(shell echo '$(javac_version_str)' | grep '[ "]1\.8[\. "$$]')
 else # default
 required_version := "1.7.x"
 required_javac_version := "1.7"
-java_version := $(shell echo '$(java_version_str)' | grep '^java .*[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]')
+java_version := $(shell echo '$(java_version_str)' | grep '^openjdk .*[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]')
 javac_version := $(shell echo '$(javac_version_str)' | grep '[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]')
 endif # if EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA8
```

Note it was `grep`'ing for `'^java .*[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]'` and I changed it to `'^openjdk .*[ "]1\.7[\. "$$]'`.

After that, I issued `m` to make again.

Hope this can help someone else out there. :)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an OpenJDK 8 build but your version is
java version "1.7.x" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.x) Java HotSpot(TM)

You need Java 7 like the error message states. Download OpenJdk 7, and install it. Then you need to

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

On both of those choose 1.7 or 7 for the version.
Google and XDA has this covered already... Java-8 will be used for Android N going forward, but for KK and MM, you need 7.

Comment: You might also need to run 'ccache -C' and bring up a new terminal, and even sometimes a restart helps.

Comment: https://nathanpfry.com/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-15-10-wily-werewolf-to-compile-android-roms/